# How do I embed Unicode G Cleff in a Verbatim environment?

Tags: unicode, input-encodings, fancyvrb, python

I am writing a chapter on Unicode. I'm using LaTeX using the `fancyvrb` chapter and `inputenc`, which lets me type most unicode characters without problem.

Problem: I want to include a character from the Supplementary Code Plane. Specifically the G Clef. Here is the code I want:

```
\begin{Verbatim}
>>> cleff=u"\U0001D11E"
>>> len(cleff)
2
>>> type(cleff)
<type 'unicode'>
>>> cleff[0]
u'\ud834'
>>> cleff[1]
u'\udd1e'
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdout.write(cleff.encode('utf-8')+"\n")

>>> 
\end{Verbatim}
```

By the way, this won't show up properly on your browser unless you can show these funky Unicode characters as well. (See https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/102205/should-utf-16-be-considered-harmful for an explanation).

My question --- is there any way to do this?

Comment: Which font are you using? And, which TeX engine (pdftex, xetex, luatex) are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to typeset many speical unicode characters, don't use `inputenc`, you should use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX with a unicode font.

Furthermore, your font should have this symbol. I don't have any font which contains U+1D11E. Thus I can't give you a real example.

---

Alternatively, you can escape to LaTeX to typeset the symbol or include a graphic. You don't have to use XeTeX or LuaTeX. And you don't have to have any fonts for the symbol — it doesn' matter.

Since I can hardly find a font for G-Cleff, this method is more practicable.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\font\musixfont="musix11" at 7pt
\newcommand\cleff{{\musixfont G}} % G-Cleff symbol from MusixTeX fonts

\begin{document}

\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\$\{\}]
>>> cleff=u"\U0001D11E"
>>> len(cleff)
2
>>> type(cleff)
<type 'unicode'>
>>> cleff[0]
u'\ud834'
>>> cleff[1]
u'\udd1e'
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdout.write(cleff.encode('utf-8')+"\n")
$cleff
>>> 
\end{Verbatim}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the comment. How do you post the output of the LaTeX? Does the blog do that automatically, or do you need to upload that somewhere?  For various reasons I do not want to use xetex. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: @vy32: Upload an image. The image I posted is just a screen snapshot.

Comment: Thanks. I thought (had hoped?) that this LaTeX blog would have a way of just doing an eval or something.